# Java While Loop

Tags: java, while-loop

Is it possible to mid while loop, return to the beginning of the loop?

Something like this

```
 while(this is true)
 {
      do stuff...
      if(this is true)
        {
            restart while loop;
        }
  }
```

Adding clarity: I did not mean restart as in reset variables, I mean restart in the sense of stopping execution and going on to the next iteration.

Comment: Won't `continue;` do exactly that?

Comment: what do you mean by "restart", reset all variables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the `continue` keyword will do that

```
while(this is true)
 {
      do stuff...
      if(this is true)
        {
            continue;
        }
  }
```

Basically, `continue` stops execution of the loop on the spot, and then goes on to the next iteration of the loop. you can do this with other loops such as `for` loops too.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Java provides labels for loops or statement blocks and it must precede a statement.
Syntax is `identifier:`

```
START: while(this is true)
 {
      do stuff...
      if(this is true)
        {
            continue START;
        }
  }
```

There are many more ways to do this but i consider this the simplest method.

Answer (score -2):

[EDIT] Misunderstood the question! This works if you want to restart the loop.

There are many ways you can do it. You can have the while loop in a function and call the function. Such as:

```
public static void loop(){
       while(this is true)  {
              do stuff...
              if(this is true) {
                   loop();
                   break; <-- dont forget this!
              }
       } 
}
```

Comment: Because of infinant looping If you never change any inputs loop() would just keep calling itself and you would be locked into an infinite loop.

Comment: This will lead to a StackOverflowError (or similar) in any possible language.

Comment: @EricSauer  I didn't personally downvote, because You did give an answer to the question that the OP asked(if you take it literally), but I can understand why others would downvote it.  You probably didn't answer what the OP meant

Comment: and no, it's not guaranteed to be a stack overflow, (but the risk of SO could indeed be high)  `do stuff...` might cause `this` not to be `true`, thus not recurring infinitly.